# Paypal billing plans and billing agreements

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

what happens when you delete a paypal billing plan, with users who are already subscribed to this plan? does the subscription plan gets cancelled? and one more question would be - let's say a user has moved from a plan to an other one, do they get automatically refunded? or do I need to refund them somehow? thank you!

Comment: You'll get better answers if you split this into 2 separate questions.

Comment: Thanks Danny, let me do that